# get xml node in html page

Tags: html, xml, xmlnode

So I have this XML

```
<food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <description>
    Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread
    </description>
    <calories>600</calories>
</food>
```

I want to get just the name of the food. How can I do that?
I've already tried with this code:

```
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
    var y = x.childNodes[0];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y.nodeValue; 
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jLa6kanr/2/

Comment: var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('name')[0];

Comment: Can you provide me the full code please?

Comment: posted down here

Comment: Open the Developer Tools in your browser. Look at the Console. **Read the error messages**.

Comment: @Quentin yes, i got this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'fiddle.jshell.net'; is therefore not allowed access

Comment: @AleX6Ndru — Yes. It's a common error and Google has lots of advice on the subject. See also: The duplicate question.

Comment: i dont understand anything

Comment: someone? im almost dead here trying to fix it

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/foldername/book.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('name')[0];
    var y = x.childNodes[0];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y.nodeValue; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Look at my fiddle link from my question.

Comment: It is cross browser access issue....Please check the console and see the error

Comment: Failed to load https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198051219432/?xml=1: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Your xml and html file should be served under same domain

Comment: So I can't get the XML from Steam to my website?